# kafka consumer does not recieve messages in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

in my code bellow consumer subscribe to existing topic but doesn't receive messages from topic please help me
and it wait for messages whereas in kafka console consumer messages received properly

```
package kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SimpleConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Kafka consumer configuration settings
        String topicName = "test12";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put("key.deserializer",
                        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer",
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer
            <String, String>(props);

        //Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

        //print the topic name
        System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + topicName);
        int i = 0;

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)

                // print the offset,key and value for the consumer records.
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n",
                    record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use a new group id to see if the consumers could read messages. If it still got failed, is there any exception thrown?

Comment: Check the logs (also broker logs) for errors. Are you sure the topic name is correct?

Comment: thanks @amethystic for commenting . I try new group id but still doesn't do any thing without any exception just waiting ...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thank you for help topic name is correct.

Comment: are you running on a Mac box? Sounds like a recent issue I am working on(kafka-4348). See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4348

Comment: Sorry guys this problem was for version this is late and i apologize

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that offset is at the latest position. You can try seek from beginning.

```
        HashSet<TopicPartition> partitions = new HashSet<TopicPartition>();
        for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
            long offset = consumer.position(partition);
            System.out.println(partition.partition() + ": " + offset);
        }
        consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
```

Comment: Thanks @ashwin this problem was for upgraded version of its late to say but sorry about that